# Espresso throws error when clicking on fullscreen view with Samsuns Galaxy S3

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

I try to click on a fullscreen view with espresso, like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.id)).perform(click());
```

But gets this error:

```
Error performing 'Send down montion event' on view 'unknown'
```

...

```
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.InjectEventSecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
```

When I run the test on other devices, such as Nexus 6 and S4, the test runs fine, but on Samsung Galaxy S3 it throws this exception.

Comment: Does it fail consistently? Were you watching the device as the test ran? Sounds like a soft keyboard or some system dialog was in front of the app.

Comment: Yes, it fails consistently. And there wasn't any soft keyboard or other system dialog in front of the app..

Comment: same issue here. no answer so far :--(

Comment: i see this issue irrespective of any device. I filed a defect for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=140

Answer (score 0):

It may be happened, due to application crashing also.

I also faced the same issue. I did one mistake after that I realize it.

My mistake was application crashing when we clicking on the button. So we should follow the below steps.

1. first run the application without testcases and test manually. Then we will know where is the application crashing.
2. Then we run our test cases it should work.

Regarding espresso document we should follow the below steps

1. turn off all animations from developer-options in the setteings:

   -Window animation scale

   -Transition animation scale

   -Animator duration scale
2. close softkeyboard once you complete the edittext test cases.